# How can I lock the screen from within the Windows 10 Mobile app?

Tags: uwp, lockscreen, windows-10-universal, secondary-live-tile

I was searching through UWP API Reference and I didn't find any way how to Lock the device from within app or with Secondary Tile.

And I am frustrated, because there is a proof that it can be done.
I don't want to make any advertisements here but for example this app:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/quicktiles/9wzdncrfhzts
Can create secondary tile that just locks the screen.

How can I do it myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it is possible with the UWP libraries. I tried to do an app able to lock the screen and had to give up few week-end ago.

You could vote for such idea here :

- https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/2854511-provide-api-to-lock-unlock-the-screen-and-provi
- https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6220483-api-to-lock-the-screen

Reading the review of the application you mentioned it seems it use a “hack” to achieve the lock screen but it seems to have side effects:

- “After locking phone, the device is very hot and battery down very fast. Please fix it.”
- “However after lock screen, it cause phone very hot and extreme battery drain”
- “ sometimes after i lock the screen, the battery is getting hot until i unlock the phone”

I’m also very surprise that UWP do not offer such functionality…

Comment: Thanks. I could see so much applications with this functionality. It's sad.