# Lock Windows 10 Phone requiring sign-in

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Is there a way to programmatically activate the Windows 10 Phone lock screen and immediately upon returning from the lock screen the user would be required to sign-in with their pin?

Comment: It seems there is no API to lock or unlock the screen. Please refer the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304930/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-from-within-the-windows-10-mobile-app).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I lock the screen from within the Windows 10 Mobile app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304930/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-from-within-the-windows-10-mobile-app)